# Ubuntu with both 32bit and 64bit libcurl

Tags: 32bit-64bit, libcurl, asterisk

Im running a c++ application and Asterisk in 64bit Ubuntu machine.My C++ application needs 32bit libcurl. And Asterisk needs 64bit libcurl to do some http calls in the dialpaln.Can I keep both 32bit and 64bit libcurl in the same machine and config asterisk to lookup for 64bit libcurl?

Comment: Your question is not about programming. Pleas head over to AskUbuntu or SuperUser where your problem would fit better.

Answer (score 0):

You can have on linux both 32 or 64 libs. 32bit apps will use libc.i686 and 32bit libs, 64bit apps will use 64bit libs.